# Windows Server 2012 Local Master User

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I have a local user on my Windows 2012 machine called "Master". The description of this user is "Built-in account for administering the computer/domain". I haven't found any information about this user online. Is this user there by default or is it just local to our system?

I am taking over this environment from others who have come before me. Most of the other machines I work on are Windows 2003 Server, or Windows 2008, or what have you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the local Administrator account and it's been renamed to `Master`.

It could also be a manually created local Administrator account and whomever created it copied the description from the local Administrator account to the `Master` account.

My guess is it's the former, not the latter.

Comment: So it's not a new thing in Windows? Somebody had to do that, correct?

Comment: Correct, check the SID value.

Answer (score 0):

`wmic useraccount get name,sid` shows the SIDs of all the users. @TheCleaner- Thanks, I found it. It is indeed the Administrator, its SID is S-1-5-21-lots-of-numbers-500, and according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330 I see:

> SID: S-1-5-21domain-500 Name: Administrator Description: A user
>   account for the system administrator. By default, it is the only user
>   account that is given full control over the system.